# Which modern-day fruits require Shehechiyanu?

Tags: food, time, agriculture, eating, shehecheyanu

According to my understanding (and please, correct me if I'm wrong), the Bracha of Shehechiyanu (שהחינו) on fruits [and some vegetables?] is recited the first time one partakes of a particular *seasonal* fruit.

Which modern-day produce is actually seasonal? I may not be too familiar, but aren't almost all fruits and vegetables available year-round these days? And if so, what fruits actually require a bracha of Shehechiyanu (especially pertinent to Rosh Hashanah night)?

Comment: This is an excellent use of the "time" tag.

Comment: It depends on your location. In Israel I don't think you can get any fruit at any time of the year at a local store.

Comment: All fruits that were seasonal are still seasonal.  Some just get shipped further distances than others. (across northern/southern hemispheres)  Israel doesn't import fruits world wide, except in small quatities.  (so Avacados, for example, are always available in Tel aviv but not other places)

Comment: Even if you don't have a new fruit, you should still say Shehechiyanu on the second night kiddush. See http://torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5766/roshhashanah.html

Comment: I thought you were supposed to say shehechiyanu the first time during the year that you eat a fruit, regardless of whether that fruit is in season where you live or was shipped in?

Comment: See OC 225 (3) "*mischadaish mishono leshono*"

Comment: I thought you could say it any time you haven't eaten the fruit within 30 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shehecheyanu applies to vegetables, too (not just fruits that grow in the ground).

Some examples for Israel, in no particular order:

- spring garlic
- watermelon
- melons (the watermelon isn't a true melon)
- kiwi
- litchi
- apricots
- peaches, plums, nectarines
- grapes
- pomegranates
- figs
- cherries
- mangoes
- carobs
- hawthorn berries

Even if you don't live in Israel, I'm pretty certain you can't get all of these whenever you want.

I should add that one says Shehecheyanu on each variety of fruit, too, so this list really includes a lot more that it looks like.